# What do I lose by setting up zipWithPadding like this? (alternate zipWith in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, padding, transpose, type-variables, zipwith

This problem came up when I was trying to zip through lists of different length and I didn't want them to be cut by the shortest one. It was in a context where the list had integers that I wanted to add or multiply. My problem is how to set up the type variables so that it can be more general.

```
zipWithPadding :: a -> (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipWithPadding n f = go n f
  where
    go n f [] a  = [f n x | x <- a]
    go n f a []  = [f n x | x <- a]
    go n f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go n f xs ys
```

---

Currently, because the element to pad the lists with has to be speficied, I have to write them this way, but it begs the question of whether it needs to be custom made for each context, or simply repurposed with higher order functions.

Edit: I would like to thank Chris in the comments for the help. It made the example at the bottom possible by changing the above solution into this:

```
zipPadWith :: a -> b -> (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipPadWith n m f = go n m f
  where
    go n _ f [] a          = [f n x | x <- a]
    go _ m f a []          = [f x m | x <- a]
    go n m f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go n m f xs ys
```

---

The example being:

```
transposeWith :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
transposeWith n []       = []
transposeWith n (ms:mss) = zipPadWith n [] (:) ms (transposeWith n mss)
```

---

It transposes the list of lists without cutting content.

Comment: Suggestion: you may wish to provide two "padding" values to your `zipPadWith` function. One to pad the left list with, and one to pad the right list with. If you do, you can end up with a type signature like so: `zipPadWith :: t1 -> t2 -> (t1 -> t2 -> a) -> [t1] -> [t2] -> [a]` You could then maybe specialize this for `zipPadWith1` which takes one default "padding" value: `zipPadWith1 n = zipPadWith n n`

Comment: You could even pass for "padding" functions that operate on the element in the longer list to generate a value.  `zipPadWith :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t2 -> t1) -> (t2 -> t1 -> a) -> [t2] -> [t1] -> [a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we implement `zipPadWith` in the following manner, the application of the default value as both arguments to `f` constrains the signature to `a -> (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

```
zipPadWith _ _ [] [] = []
zipPadWith n f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipPadWith n f xs ys
zipPadWith n f (x:xs) [] = f x n : zipPadWith n f xs []
zipPadWith n f [] (y:ys) = f n y : zipPadWith n f [] ys
```

However, if the function takes *two* default arguments, one to use if the left list falls short, and one to use if the right list falls short, the type is not constrained, and can be `a -> b -> (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`.

```
zipPadWith _ _ _ [] [] = []
zipPadWith n1 n2 f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipPadWith n1 n2 f xs ys
zipPadWith n1 n2 f (x:xs) [] = f x n2 : zipPadWith n1 n2 f xs []
zipPadWith n1 n2 f [] (y:ys) = f n1 y : zipPadWith n1 n2 f [] ys
```